# Find JOBID with REXX on z/os

Tags: batch-processing, zos, rexx

Can anybody give me a hint on how I can get the **JOBID** of my **REXX**-Script submitted via a **JCL**?

JOBNAME, for example, is no problem but I haven't found a reference to the JOBID in any ControlBlock so far.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: solution found: http://bit.listserv.tsorexx.narkive.com/uM20xzru/job-id-within-an-exec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/* rexx */
/*                                                                    */
/* Get Jobname and Jobnumber by threading through MVS control blocks  */
/* Note: PSA begins at address zero, address of TCB is at offset 21C  */
/*                                                                    */
TCB = C2D(STORAGE(021C,4))            /* TCB address at '21C'X of PSA */
TIOT = C2D(STORAGE(D2X(TCB + 12), 4))   /* TIOT address at TCB + 12   */
JOBNAME = STORAGE(D2X(TIOT), 8)         /* Jobname at TIOT + 0        */
JSCB = C2D(STORAGE(D2X(TCB  + 180), 4)) /* JSCB address at TCB + 180  */
SSIB = C2D(STORAGE(D2X(JSCB + 316), 4)) /* SSIB address at JSCB + 316 */
JOBNUMBER = STORAGE(D2X(SSIB + 12), 8)  /* Job number at SSIB + 12    */
say 'JobName:' JOBNAME 'JobNumber:' JOBNUMBER
RETURN
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution addresses a different Control Block than the solution of Lindy Mayfield (see my link above). I need some time to check if this information is also available in a ASM-program running in an IMS BMP region. That would be great and would save me a lot of time. :-)